# Update query with self table based on column wise condition

Tags: mysql

I need to update the ManagerId as I have following table structure

```
    userid  EmpAccId ManagerAccId ManagerId
     1        X         Y           
     2        Y         Z
     3        Z         X
```

I need to update the above table based on EmpAccId and ManagerAccId as for userId 1 The managerId should be 2 as EmpAccId for userid 1 is X and ManagerAccId is Y and Y's userid is 2 so for userid 1 MangerId should be 2.
so the resultant table should be

```
   userId  EmpAccId ManagerAccId ManagerId
     1       X        Y             2
     2       Y        Z             3
     3       Z        X             1
```

I need a single dynamic query in sql.

Comment: This is a very interesting project, do let us know if you have a question! When you actually ask a question, pls share what you have tried, do not simply pass your work onto us!

Comment: What I have tried is another issue. If you look that I am passing it to you then dont think like that. There are so many people who are eager to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a left join to achieve this :

```
UPDATE mytable as TB1
LEFT JOIN  mytable as TB2
    ON TB1.ManagerAccId = TB2.EmpAccId 
SET TB1.ManagerId= TB2.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE tbl_a t1
INNER JOIN tbl_b t2
ON t1.EMPAccId      = t2.EMPAccId
AND t1.ManagerAccId = t2.ManagerAccId
SET t1.ManagerID    = t2.ManagerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also help you

```
    update table  t1  left join table t2 on t1.EmpAccId=t2.ManagerAccId set t2.ManagerId=t1.userId;
```